# How can we capture access_token, session_id values if no request is showing such values in response using jmeter?

Tags: post, dynamic, jmeter, state, token

We have a portal whose POST request parameters are:
**access_token**, **session_id**,**state**

But I don't see any response containing values for the above mentioned parameters at all. Is there any way I can capture it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the values in the response body, the following options remain:

1. The values are in the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), i.e. you're redirected at least once and the redirect target contains the values you're looking for in its URL
2. The values are in the [response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

   [image]

   both locations can be expected using [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and both locations can be queried using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor or Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)

   [image]
3. The values might come as the result of an [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request, [JMeter is not a browser](https://jmeter.apache.org/) and it doesn't execute JavaScript so you will need to manually simulate these calls using individual HTTP Request samplers
4. The values might be calculated by [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp) on browser side, if this is the case you will need to replicate the logic using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and Groovy language

Comment: ok any hint as in how can I go ahead with JSR223 Preprocessor for "access_token" type parameter value?